# MySQL primary key type becomes "index" after inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, where-clause

I'm working with a rather large database (500+ millions entries), and am trying to optimize the search engine.

I have 3 tables:

**items**
(id, data)

**item_terms**
(id, term)

**item_term_results**
(id, item_term_id, item_id)

item_terms.id is a unique index, and item_term_id is an index.

When trying the following query, everything goes well and I get exactly what I want, being the ids of the items I'm searching for, with good performances.

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_term_results.item_id FROM item_terms
    INNER JOIN item_term_results ON item_terms.id = item_term_results.item_term_id
    WHERE item_terms.term = 'Jason'
```

And the explain returns that the query has a type "const" on item_terms and "ref" on item_term_results. Great.

**But**, now I want to add another WHERE closure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_term_results.item_id FROM item_terms
    INNER JOIN item_term_results ON item_terms.id = item_term_results.item_term_id
    WHERE item_terms.term = 'Jason'
    OR item_terms.term = 'Bourne'
```

**Surprise**! The query has now a type of "index" on item_terms, even if item_term is a unique index.

Any idea why? How could I solve this problem? I can't move from mysql to another DB at this point, and in every cases I'll need to have multiple WHERE cases.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you have a typo in `item.terms.term`? Do you mean `item_terms.term`?

Comment: @BillKarwin I think so

Comment: Yes, sorry. I fixed it. I actually rewrote the queries to simplify them here with generic table names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple where clauses, use IN if it is the same field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_term_results.item_id
  FROM item_terms
 INNER JOIN item_term_results
    ON item_terms.id = item_term_results.item_term_id
 WHERE item_terms.term in ('Jason','Bourne')
```

And as an FYI, the primary key is always indexed.

Comment: edited b/c I didn't realize the 2 fields in your where clause were different, the table prefix confused me.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I miswrote the query when redacting this post. I was actually doing the exact same query as yours. However, I also tried using IN, but it produces the same problem: the query has a type "index" on item_term_results.

Comment: Are they the same field? You probably should use IN, did you mean "item_terms.term = 'Bourne'   (notice the underscore not the period)?

Comment: I don't understand why you think it's a problem that it's using an index on the item_term_results table. You're joining into it on item_term_id. If that field is indexed why would you not want that index to be used?

Comment: I'm sorry again. Yes I meant item_terms.term.

Comment: As for your second comment, I'm not talking about the actual index, but how mysql performs the query. If you place "EXPLAIN" before your query, mysql outputs some useful informations telling you how your query is optimized. If for "type" the value is "const", then the query performs very fast. if it is "index" it isn't optimized properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58126/discussion-between-manu-epita-and-brian-demilia).